# How to obtain a taylor series of sine in Fortran

Tags: loops, fortran, expansion, trigonometry

My goal is to find a Maclaurin series of sine, where the program return 3 things: the expansion of an angle in degrees provided by the user with the precision of 10^⁻15, the first term discard to get that precision and the sine calculated from the function sine(x). Here is my program:

```
          program serie de taylor seno
             implicit none 
             integer*8  N, i, j
             real*8  serie, x, xrad
             real*8 xtest, pi, senx, func, ten, fat
             write(*,*)"Choose en angle in degrees"
             read(5,*) x
             fat = 1.d0
             ten = 10**(-15)
             senx = 0.d0
             pi= datan2(0.d0,-1.d0)
             xrad = (x*pi)/180.d0
             xtest = (x*pi)/180.d0
             func =dsin(xtest)
             i = 0
             do while (serie .ge. ten)
                   do j = 1, 2*i +1
                      fat = fat*j
                   end do
                   N = (2*i)+1
                   serie = (((-1)**i)*(xrad**N))/fat
                   senx = senx + serie
                   i = i + 1
                   fat = 1
             end do
             write(*,*)senx
             write (*,*) i
             write(*,*)func
          end program serie de taylor seno
```

My problem is that the loop of do while only runs twice for any angle. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I see several issues. First, what is `dez`? You should always use `implicit none` to catch mistakes like that.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to translate that term, and I added the implicit none, but still doesn't work

Comment: `serie` hasn't been defined before the conditional of the loop is first evaluated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, you've got the right idea, but there are several issues. When trying to debug like this, you should include verbose output during each loop iteration to try to track down exactly what's happening. The problems I found are:

- You must compare the tolerance to the *magnitude* of `serie`. The Taylor series of sin includes negative terms, and the first negative term is causing your loop to exit (on the second one, every time).
- The tolerance you set is actually 0. `10**(-15)` contains only integers, so the answer is evaluated as an integer. Use `10.**(15)`, or better yet `1.e-15`.
- Your program name cannot have spaces, at least for my version of `gfortran` and `ifort`. Edit: apparently this is because I copied your code into free form, thanks francescalus
- To make sure the `while` loop is entered the first time, before any series is evaluated, define `serie` to some large value.

In addition, I have the following other recommendations:

- Do not use non-portable kind modifiers such as `real*8`. Depending on the system, you will get different answers. Select your kind using, for example, `REAL_SELECTED_KIND` or `REAL64`. Because you're requesting a given tolerance, the best thing to do is request that tolerance of your real kinds.
- Similarly, do not use `datan` and `dsin` - using the generic function instead will be kind-independent and will evaluate to the precision of the variable it's given.
- Instead of setting the factorial to `1` at the end of the loop, which requires a separate initialization, just set it right before the loop to compute the factorial.
- You do not need 8-byte integers here.
- Just because the last term is less than a tolerance doesn't necessarily mean the series is converged to that tolerance. The sum of many terms could give you a problem, although this is probably not a problem for sin series that converge rapidly.
- Unit `5` is usually the standard input but not always. `read(*,...` will connect to the standard input, or use `INPUT_UNIT` from `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV`.
- What is `xteste` used for? Is it supposed to be `xtest`?
- Set variables that shouldn't change, such as pi and tolerance, to parameters.
- Comment your code! It's not very readable right now. Think about what you would think if you came back to it in a year. I've also kept the debugging output I used to check that the code is working. This kind of output is good for beginners to learn.

All told, your fixed program looks like:

```
program taylor
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: wp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
   real(wp), parameter :: pi = atan2(0._wp,-1._wp)
   real(wp), parameter :: ten = 1.e-15_wp

   integer :: N, i, j
   real(wp) :: serie, x, xrad
   real(wp) :: xtest, senx, func, fat

   ! -- Initialization
   write(*,*) "Choose an angle in degrees"
   read(*,*) x

   senx = 0._wp
   xrad = (x*pi)/180._wp
   xtest = (x*pi)/180_wp

   func = sin(xtest)

   ! -- Main loop
   i = 0
   serie = huge(serie)
   do while (abs(serie) .ge. ten)

      ! -- Compute factorial
      fat = 1._wp
      do j=1,2*i+1
         fat = fat*j
      enddo

      ! -- Evaluate i-th term in series
      N = (2*i)+1
      serie = (((-1)**i)*(xrad**N))/fat
      senx = senx + serie
      i = i + 1

      write(*,*) 'Completed iteration ', i
      write(*,*) 'serie, senx: ', serie, senx
   enddo

   write(*,*) 'Completed while loop'

   write(*,*) 'senx: ', senx
   write (*,*) 'i: ', i
   write(*,*) 'func: ', func

end program taylor
```

Which gives the correct output for me:

```
mach5% gfortran main.f90 && ./a.out
 Choose an angle in degrees
30
 Completed iteration            1
 serie, senx:   0.52359877559829882       0.52359877559829882     
 Completed iteration            2
 serie, senx:   -2.3924596203935038E-002  0.49967417939436376     
 Completed iteration            3
 serie, senx:    3.2795319442867078E-004  0.50000213258879245     
 Completed iteration            4
 serie, senx:   -2.1407197692357951E-006  0.49999999186902322     
 Completed iteration            5
 serie, senx:    8.1512566573875745E-009  0.50000000002027989     
 Completed iteration            6
 serie, senx:   -2.0315575399030637E-011  0.49999999999996431     
 Completed iteration            7
 serie, senx:    3.5702758612702185E-014  0.50000000000000000     
 Completed iteration            8
 serie, senx:   -4.6610066605152958E-017  0.49999999999999994     
 Completed while loop
 senx:   0.49999999999999994     
 i:            8
 func:   0.49999999999999994
```

A final note about assigning an integer value to a real number, such as `fat=1._wp`. It would be the same to simply say `fat=1`, or `fat=1.`. However, assigning a non-integer value using the same notation, such as `fat=1.5`, experiences a loss of precision, so the correct notation is `fat=1.5_wp`. So I tend to keep my notation consistent everywhere and use `fat=1._wp` for simplicity.

Comment: Whether the `program` statement may have blanks in it later depends on whether it is fixed- or free-form source.

Comment: To be precise in Fortran terminology, it isn't necessary to _initialize_ `serie`, merely to have it _defined_ before the reference.

Comment: @francescalus I've added the recommended changes, thanks!

Comment: @Ross Thank you, I'll keep in mind your suggestions, specially the use of the selected_real_kind ( , ), how to keep track of the loop and the overall organization of my program. About the real*8 and the datan2( ) and dsen(  ), it was a recommendation of my teacher, since I will be working with double precision. I'll talk to her about that later.